# 2D integral on a non-regular grid

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have two arrays `coord` and `values`. The first one contains a set of 2D coordinates on a grid of size N*N. The second contains the values of a function F on each of these coordinates. For instance on a 5*5 grid, I have the following 10 coordinates and values:

```
coord = np.array([(0,0),(2,1),(0,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,0),(1,3),(4,2),(3,0),(1,4)])
values = np.array([1,5,1,4,6,3,2,0,5,2])
```

which look like this on the grid:

```
4|  x 2 x 6 x
3|  x 2 4 x x
2|  1 x x x 0
1|  x x 5 x x
0|  1 x x 5 3
^   _ _ _ _ _     
Y X>0 1 2 3 4
```

I wish to compute the integral of the function F in Python, and to do so, I use the following code:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

coord = coord.swapaxes(0,1)
nx = np.unique(coord[1]).size
ny = np.unique(coord[0]).size
intg_x = np.zeros(nx)

for x in range(nx):
    indices = np.where(coord[1] == x)[0]
    v = values[indices]
    c = coord[0][indices]
    intg_x[x] = integrate.trapz(v,c)

intg = integrate.trapz(intg_x,np.unique(coord[0]).sort())
print(intg)

Out[1]: -3.0
```

However, when using it on the above example, it outputs 3 which is obviously wrong. What is wrong with this code? Is there any way to improve its performance for large sets of coordinates?

Comment: Do you consider to use spicy RegularGridInterpolator to get missed points?

Comment: The thing is I'm doing this intentionally so that I have less points to integrate over. In the full code, I integrate over the whole space twice, so I need to have an irregular grid with not as many points as the full regular grid, for time purposes.

Comment: ok, what output do you expect in your case example?

Comment: Well I would like to get as close as possible to what the "true" function integral would be, I don't know what is the best way to do this [in the full code, there are a ~100,000 points over a 400*400*400 sized regular grid]. Here, if we use a simple trapezoidal rule, we should get : integral_x = [13, 0, 2.5, 3, 8] and integral = 16. I don't know if there are better solutions than this one to integrate, but making this one work would already be great.

Comment: How fast should the 3d integral be for the 400x400x400 array? Why do you not reduce the over all resolution to for example (100x100x100)?

Comment: I only integrate on ~100,000 points for time purposes and it already takes my laptop about 5 to 10 minutes, because it's a double integral. I already have a program that does the integration on a regular grid (sized ~50*50*40), which is pretty easy to write. But the results are not satisfactory, because the function I'm trying to integrate varies a lot (from 10E-8 to 10E2 depending on the region of space), so I created a grid that is very precise where the function is high, and less precise where the function is low, choosing random points from the ~400*400*400 grid. I hope it's clearer now !